# Learning Suggestion to better understanding on Advanced Microeconometrics (Master Degree Level)

Tags: econometrics, statistics

I am studying master in Economics and currently taking the compulsory course of Econometrics in which I have problem in understanding the materials. It is a must for me to pass this course in current semester, but I have little confidence to succeed it with my knowledge at this time. The book used in the course is "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data" by Jeffrey Wooldridge.

I don't have the proper basic understanding of first three chapters in the book consisted of The Stochastic Setting and Asymptotic Analysis, Conditional Expectations and Related Concepts in Econometrics, and  Basic Asymptotic Theory. Therefore, it would be tougher to understand the following chapters.

So what is your suggestion for me to figure out this? Perhaps the beginner-friendly books of Statistics or Econometrics? Or other tips and trics?

Maybe some of you have experienced the same situation in the past, then you can share how you figured out and have done with this problem.

I appreciate for your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think woodridge would be difficult as a first book for someone with no background in econometrics. check out baltagi or johnston for a gentler introduction. also, peter kennedy's book is not really a text but gives very intuition for the different concepts.  Also, wooldridridge's intro book might be useful.

Comment: Have you tried Introduction to financial econometrics by Chris brooks?

Comment: IMHO. when trying to gain an understanding of econometrics, it's best to not to mix it in with finance by studying financial econometrics instead. Chris Brooks  text is quite nice and the level is reasonable ( strikes a nice balance between theory and applied ) but it mixes the two subjects  which I think can add extra complexity that a person getting into econometrics doesn't need, atleast initially.

Answer (score 1):

This youtube channel has excellent videos for metrics:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3tFZR3eL1bDY8CqZDOQh-w